# How to copy the most updated commit in github

Tags: git

I don't know the right words so I am having trouble finding the solution.

I `git clone` a repository in github from my computer. and now there is an updated one in github and I want to copy it to my computer.

when I `git clone` again, this is the output `fatal: destination path 'myFolder' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

How can I copy the latest and updated repository in github.

Sorry if this is a duplicate question but I haven't found anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+local+repository

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. and sorry that it is a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `git pull` to get the latest commits from a repository.

[Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Comment: What if OP does *not* want it merged into his local branch?

Comment: He marked the response as correct, so this is what he wanted to do.

Comment: ...and SO questions are *not* intended to be useful to *one* person. To be fair, in my comment I shouldn't have written "OP" but "one".

Comment: You can always suggest an edit :)

Comment: Given the popularity of my answer, for the sake of yours I'd rather not to ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` is the command you should use. In future as well if there are new updates available, you don't have to checkout your code every time. `git pull` should pull the all the latest code from master branch to your local repository.

hope this clarifies your queries.